# Ubuntu Gnome 16.06 Gnome 3.18.15 Sluggish with plenty of free memory

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, gnome-shell

CD-Based standard install of Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.

I've been putting the move to Linux off for a long time, and I've always loved Ubuntu Gnome, so I went for it.

Everything was running pretty smoothly till this morning. Recently went through a move just after install, so I haven't been able to actually "get to work" on the new install till this morning.

Running a 4790k at 4.4 an all cores, Nvidia GTX 970, 16GB of RAM (with more than half free when slowdown happens)

Just this morning started running multiple desktops across two monitors. Switching, tabbing and switching workspaces is terribly slow, but CPU maintains low utilization. Max memory used with several browsers, eclipse,  music playing, etc. Top & free show nothing of significance happening.

Any direction you could point me would be great. Thanks!

Comment: this is a desktop? the move may have jiggled a connection. try pressing cards back into slots

Comment: "Slow" is relative. Could be anything from graphics card to wireless card. Is lubuntu slow ?